# Java language using instead of groovy fro archetype-post-generate

Tags: java, maven, groovy, archetypes

I need write a script to execute after to generate my new projects with my custom archetype with maven, but I need to know if I can use **java** instead of **groovy** language execute a process after to generate my new projects.

my archetype is be using in **localhost**.

Comment: Most Java code will run in groovy as well. Java syntax is mostly valid groovy syntax.

Comment: thank for your help and advice. that's working like a charm.